# Obtaining value parameter of a HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to obtain the `value` parameter of an HTML element when this element is clicked. My code is as follows:

```js
const dothis = () => {
  var btnContainer = document.getElementById("btnContainer");

  var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("page-item");

  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");

      if (current.length > 0) {
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
      }

      this.className += " active";

    });
  }

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="page-item" value="ABC" onclick="dothis()"><a class="page-link" href="#">Put ABC</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page-item" value="DCF" onclick="dothis()"><a class="page-link" href="#">Put DCF</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I obtain the `value` **ABC** from the `<li>` tag using javascript?

Comment: you can send value parameter to `dothis()` method like: `<li class="page-item" value="ABC" onclick="dothis(this.value)">` then obtain parameter inside function.

Comment: When I console log I get 0 and not ABC

Comment: Why are you adding event listeners in an event listener? Remove `onclick="dothis()"` and add `window.addEventListener("load", dothis);`.

Answer (score 2):

`li` items support `value` only for ordered lists and it is the starting point for the list. (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp).

I'd recommend to use `data` attributes and refer to them, like:

```
<li class="page-item" data-value="DCF" onclick="dothis()">
    <a class="page-link" href="#">Put DCF</a>
</li>
```

And then you refer to `data-value` in code, e.g.:

```
document.querySelector('#your_id').dataset.value
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers. Furthermore `value` is a valid attribute for `li`, but it can only contain numbers ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#Attributes)). You can try using `data`-attributes:

```js
{
  console.log(`li.value can only be a number, so this will print '0': ${
    document.querySelector("body > ul > li:nth-child(1)").value}`);
  document.addEventListener(`click`, evt => {
      if (evt.target.classList.contains(`page-link`)) { 
        console.log( evt.target.parentNode.dataset.value ); 
      }
  });
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="page-item" value="NOTVALID" data-value="ABC"><a class="page-link" href="#">Put ABC</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page-item" data-value="DCF"><a class="page-link" href="#">Put DCF</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

- You called `doThis` `onClick`, which then itself added an event listener each time you clicked. That's not what you wanted I guess, so stick with one. It's recommended to not use event attributes at all, but do it all with JS alone.
- You remove the `active` className from the first element with that class in the whole document. Should be limited to the active page-item in the `#btnContainer`
- Use `data-value` attribute instead of `value`, so you can use `dataset`
- Use `classList` instead of mangling with `className`
- By using `forEach` instead of a loop, I have a local variable that is my target

```js
!(function() {
  var btnContainer = document.getElementById('btnContainer');

  var btns = (el) => el.getElementsByClassName('page-item');
  var active = (el) => el.getElementsByClassName('active');

  Array.from(btns(btnContainer)).forEach((btn, idx, ar) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      Array.from(active(btnContainer)).forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'))
      e.target.classList.add("active");
      console.log(btn.dataset.value)
    })


  })

}());
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}

* {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul id="btnContainer">
  <li class="page-item" data-value="ABC"><a class="page-link" href="#">Put ABC</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page-item" data-value="DCF"><a class="page-link" href="#">Put DCF</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

if want obtain the value ABC from the

```
document.getElementsByClassName("page-item")[0].getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score -1):

I did the following and it worked.

```
const dothis = () => {
  var btnContainer = document.getElementById("btnContainer");

  var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("page-item");

  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(value) {
      var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");

      if (current.length > 0) {
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
      }

      this.className += " active";

      var storage = localStorage;
      var event = value.toElement.text;

      storage.setItem("clicked_event", event);
      var stored_clicked_event = storage.getItem("clicked_event");
      console.log(stored_clicked_event);

    });
  }

}
```

then.. i changed HTML to:

```
<ul>
  <li class="page-item" value="ABC" onclick="dothis(this.value)"><a class="page-link" href="#">Put ABC</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page-item" value="DCF" onclick="dothis(this.value)"><a class="page-link" href="#">Put DCF</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```